# How does the continuous integration game (ci-game) plug in in Hudson/Jenkins with multiple committers

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I am trying to implement the ci-game in our Hudson to capture who is breaking the build most of the time. [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin) and [again here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin), it is explained that this plugin adds scores to comitters for successful build and deduct scores when the build is broken. My problem is that, in an environment where there are multiple comitters, how does the game deduct the scores from the comitter who broke the build when there are others who have also committed but did not break the build? Or does it just simply deducts points from all committers who committed since the last successful build?

Comment: If you wanna play that game and are using Git as version control, I'd suggest you use Gerrit code review tool, that is well integrated with Jenkins. It triggers a new build for each commit, and that commit can only be merged into master if the build succeeds. With this, the build is NEVER broken.

Comment: @rcomblen our SCM is subversion and BTW, the projects are .NET not java.

Answer (score 3):

The Jenkins game awards/punishes everyone that have participated in a build. So if someone breaks the code and commits at the same time as another person commits, both will be punished by the game. The shorter the SCM poll time, the less chance for this to happen.

The game works per build only, ie it does not check old builds to calculate the score. So if the build is broken, the following builds (while it is broken) will not give any "build" points at all. When the build is fixed, the user who fixed it will receive 1 point regardles on who broke the build.

Answer (score 1):

The last committer will always get all the points. This means that if the previous committer broke the build the last committer will have negative score. Same thing is that when the last committer just made a simple change but the previous committer fixed a 100 issues the last committer will take the points.